# How to stylize text-list and other elements?

Tags: rebol

Default Rebol VID style is eye-searing, put bluntly. I started making my own default, but ran into a snag. Namely, how do I specify styles for a sub-element of an element?

```
good-looking: stylize [
  field: field 
    edge [size: 1x1]
    colors [255.255.255 255.255.255]
  area: area
    edge [size: 1x1]
    colors [255.255.255 255.255.255]
  text-list: text-list
    ;text-list/sub-area/edge [size: 1x1]
]
```

I want all fields to have a thin border, including text-list and others. But I have no idea how to include that rule in the text-list definition.

Also, how to reduce repetition with styles, like with the colors?

Comment: This question has also been asked and answered (or at least discussed) over on rebolforum:   http://www.rebolforum.com/index.cgi?f=printtopic&topicnumber=45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first:

```
layout [X: field]
type? X/edge
type? X/colors
```

Objects should get re-made to avoid unexpected side-effects on the shared ones.

```
good-looking: stylize [
  field: field with [
    edge: make edge [size: 1x1]
    colors: copy [255.255.255 255.255.255]
  ]
  area: area with [
    edge: make edge [size: 1x1]
    colors: copy [255.255.255 255.255.255]
  ]
  text-list: text-list with [
    sub-area: make sub-area [
      edge: make edge [size: 1x1]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can partly answer your first question. At the REBOL consol, try this...

```
>> lo: layout [t: text-list]
```

That both creates a layout and allows the text-list object (t) to be examined using PROBE...

```
>> probe first t
== [self type offset size span pane text color image effect data edge font para feel saved-area rate show? options parent-face old-offset old-size line-list changes face-flags action state access style alt-action facets related words colors texts images file var keycode reset styles init multi blinker pane-size dirty? help user-data flags doc xy sz iter sub-area sld sn lc picked cnt act slf lines text-pane update resize]
```

Notice the SUB-AREA there. That's the list area in a text-list. Probe into that and you get...

```
>> probe first t/sub-area/edge
== [self color image effect size]
>> probe first t/sub-area/edge/size
== 2
```

So, change SIZE there and view the layout we made...

```
>> t/sub-area/edge/size: 1x1
== 1x1
>> view lo
```

The text-list's edge should be thin now. I'm not sure how you achieve that using style, but hopefully this will put you on the right track.